# Logging geoserver's request logs into postgres

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to force geoserver to write request.log(s) into a postgis database. Unfortunately, geoserver's documentation remains silent about logging into database at all.

Searching the web I found one answer on mailing list for similar question. I didn't try this, but that's because I've got feeling that's not thing I'm looking for, because this solution seems to allow to save to database logs of geoserver's activity not incoming request what is my point...

I also found geoserver's plugin called monitor, which could be thing I'm looking for, (again) unfortunately in v 2.3 adding it brakes answers for Request=GetFeatureInfo, so it's useless for me.

Finally, there's always a solution to use PostgreSQL COPY to import data from logfiles into database, but I think there have to be more elegant way.

The point is to log requests into database, so after little post-processing on request strings, I'll be able to write simple reports of IPs using my server or most commonly downloaded areas.

More specified question is: where can I find settings for request logs and how to reconfigure it to put data into database?

Can anybody help?

Comment: I've never tried that, but I think you should study log4j. [Geoserver uses log4j](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/advanced/logging.html), and log4j can be configured to write to a PostgreSQL database. This question might be a [starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727959/log4j-to-database).

Comment: Yes, but a piece of linked specification is about logs in $GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/logs folder - where geoserver is placing logs of his own work. All case is about logs of requests to geoserver and they are placed in geoserver/logs folder (not in data_dir).

Comment: Incoming requests are not Geoserver work before the servlet container (Tomcat, Jetty) is passing them on. Search how to config Tomcat/Jetty if that's what you are interested in.